# Tornadofx - Keeping globally accessed properties in a ViewModel?

Tags: kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

### Reasoning:

Hello guys. I'm building an evolution simulator as personal project. I have a few parameters set on textfields, such as the speed of the simulation and the number of "organisms". These are going to be accessed by multiple components of the application. Because i would also like to use validation on a few parameters, I set up a ViewModel like such:

```
class ParametersModel: ViewModel() {
    // These properties would likely be DoubleProperty, but for simplicity lets pretend they are strings
    val simulationSpeed = bind { SimpleStringProperty() }
    val organismsGenerated = bind { SimpleStringProperty() }
}
```

... and then perform the validation tests on the textfields:

```
val model = ParametersModel()
textfield(model.simulationSpeed).required()
```

This works alright, but the issue with it is that I'm defining the model properties as a bind to an empty `SimpleDoubleProperty`, which is redundant since I'm never commiting this model (the program should always read changes as they are typed). At the same time, I cant define the model properties as simply:

```
class ParametersModel: ViewModel() {
    val simulationSpeed = SimpleStringProperty()
    val organismsGenerated = SimpleStringProperty()
}
```

Because I then get an error about the validation:

```
The addValidator extension can only be used on inputs that are already bound bidirectionally to a property in a Viewmodel. Use validator.addValidator() instead or make the property's bean field point to a ViewModel.
```

The other option I could take would be to make a class named something like GlobalProperties, which would keep my properties and also a ValidationContext. I could then add validators by using `validationContext.addValidator` and pass the textfields. But at this point I feel I'm just coding a ViewModel equivalent.

### Question:

Is ViewModel the correct way of keeping "globally" accessed parameters set by textfields? If so, is there a way to not have to set the model properties as a bind of an empty one, since i dont ever need to commit anything?

Comment: It seems a little weird to me that you are trying to use the validation without using the commit functionality. What do you do when validation fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would use a `ViewModel` with some sort of model. Then you can use the `ViewModel` to handle user input, which stores the current state of the user input, and the backing model will only be update when the `ViewModel` is committed, assuming validation passes (which seems at odds with your claim that you "dont ever need to commit anything").

Something like this:

```kotlin
class Parameters {
    val simulationSpeedProperty = SimpleStringProperty(...)
    var simulationSpeed by simulationSpeedProperty

    val organismsGeneratedProperty = SimpleStringProperty(...)
    var organismsGenerated by organismsGeneratedProperty
}

class ParametersModel(parameters: Parameters): ItemViewModel<Parameters>(parameters) {
    val simulationSpeed = bind(Parameters::simulationSpeedProperty)
    val organismsGenerated = bind(Parameters::organismsGeneratedProperty)
}
```

Then you can be sure that the `Parameters` backing the `ParametersModel` always has valid values in it (assuming of course it was initialized with valid values).

Comment: Uhmm, so the properties of a ViewModel update regardless of validation? I was under the impression that they would be validated and only then updated... And that commiting would only be necessary if i need to apply logic before updating the actual parameters. I see now, thanks for your answer!

Comment: "Uhmm, so the properties of a ViewModel update regardless of validation?" Technically yes, though that's a weird way of thinking about it. It would make more sense to think of the properties of the ViewModel holding the current state of the UI, including both user entered data, as well as any associated validation. It then acts as a sort of sentinel between the unsafe world of user input and the comparatively safe world of your internal data.

Comment: Testing confirmed the ViewModel properties update regardless of validation, I'll accept your answer. This is what was throwing me off...